# Can i detect more than 40 devices in one time and keep tracking by BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

So I will have more than 40+ devices in one place and I need to record when device entered in my zone and also when i lost signal by BLE.
As i know there are only 20 regions limit in IOS in one time.
As i can't set regions on peoples devices , is it means that i can't track more than 20 devices or is there any way to do it?

Devices will be iPhone,apple watch , androids.
So i guess they will have different UUID.

Comment: As long as all beacons are using the same uuid then you can use beacon ranging to determine their proximity. The 20 region limit won't apply since all beacons will be in a single region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the 20 beacon region limit on iOS, but that probably will not impact your solution for a number of reasons:

- The limit is per region not per device as @paulw11 says, so you can track much more than 20 beacons if you define regions that match multiple beacons by using wildcard idebtifiers in the regions.
- You cannot make an apple watch transmit as a beacon.  And while iPhone and most Android devices can do this, iPhones must have your custom app in the foreground to transmit.  This may not work for you depending on your use case.

An alternative to having the devices transmit is to have them receive a beacon signal from a fixed beacon transmitter you install.  This can be done by a custom app in the background (although for Apple watch it must be tied to a nearby iPhone for this to work).  With this approach, there is no limit to the number of devices you can track.  This is the typical way this is done.